# Show that $\det(xA+yB+zI_{n})=\det(yA+xB+zI_{n})$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, contest-math, determinant, characteristic-polynomial

We have $A$ and $B$ $(n×n)$ matrices with complex entries. We know that $A-B=AB-BA$. Show that $$\det(xA+yB+zI_{n})=\det(yA+xB+zI_{n})$$
for every $x,y,z$ complex numbers with $x+y≠0$.
We can see that $\operatorname{Tr}(A)=\operatorname{Tr}(B)$. I tried to suppose $A$ or $B$ are invertible and try changing $A-B=AB-BA$ somehow, but I dont know if that helps. We can also see that $$\operatorname{Tr}(xA+yB)=\operatorname{Tr}(yA+xB)=(x+y)\operatorname{Tr}(A).$$ The conclusion looks like we need to show that $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$. Maybe some calculus and we can use the continuity of polynomial functions? I also minded calculating the determinants using polynomial forms.

Comment: You can use characteristic polynom (with $z$ instead of $-z$ it changes nothing) :

$$ \det(xA+yB+zI_n)=\chi_{xA+yB}(z)$$

Comment: I think this question had been asked before, but I cannot find the duplicate. Essentially, if you put $N=A-B$, then $N=[N,B]$. Therefore $[N,B]$ is nilpotent, by Jacobson's lemma. Hence $N$ is nilpotent. Then it should be possible to use a subspace chain argument to show that $N$ and $B$ are simultaneously triangulable. Therefore $\det((x+y)B+tN+zI)$ does not depend on $t$ and the result follows immediately.

Comment: Another approach: by proposition 1.5 of Gerald Bourgeois, *Pair of matrices, one of which commutes with their commutator*, Electronic J. Lin. Alg., vol. 22, pp.593-597, June 2011, if $[X,[X,Y]]=0$, then the pair of matrices $Y$ and $[X,Y]$ has Taussky‘s property L. In your case, by putting $X=N$ and $Y=B$, we see that $(N,B)$ has property L. Hence the result.

Comment: @user1551 do I need to prove the propriety L in contest conditions?

Comment: @user1551 Yes. Another thing about this problem: can we show that xA+yB and yB+xA are similar?

Comment: If this is a contest question, I think the contestants are not even expected to *know* property L, let alone to *prove* it or to prove that some pairs of matrices satisfy it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m making this an answer to flesh out the approach hinted by the post author and that I completed.

Write $A=X+Y$, $B=X-Y$, then $2(YX-XY)=AB-BA=2Y$ so $Y=YX-XY$.

Moreover, for any $x,y,z \in \mathbb{C}$, $xA+yB+zI_n=(x+y)X+(x-y)Y+zI_n$. Thus the problem is solved if we can prove that $\det(aX+bY+cI_n)$ is an even function of $b$.

Note that it’s enough to show, by continuity of the determinant, that for any $a \neq 0$ and any $c$ such that $X’=X+c/a I_n$ is invertible, that the function $b \longmapsto \det(aX+bY+cI_n)$ is even.

But for such $a,c$, $\det(aX+bY+cI_n)=\det(aX’+bY)=\det(X’)\det(aI_n+b(X’)^{-1}Y)$. This is an even function of $b$ (constant, in fact) as long as $Z=(X’)^{-1}Y$ is nilpotent.

Now, note that $YX’-X’Y=Y$: this implies (formally) that $ZX’-X’Z=Z$.

It is then standard to show that $Z$ is nilpotent. For instance, you can show by induction on $k$ that $Z^kX’-X’Z^k=kZ^k$: in particular, if $Z$ is not nilpotent, every $k \geq 1$ is an eigenvalue of the endomorphism $T \longmapsto TX’-X’T$, which is impossible since we’re in finite dimension.

Comment: Please accept user1551’s answer instead, it was the earlier one and I wouldn’t have found this if it weren’t for their solution.

Answer (score 1):

From the given condition, we get $N=[N,B]$ where $N=A-B$. Therefore $[N,B]$ is nilpotent, by Jacobson's lemma. Hence $N$ is nilpotent, because it is equal to $[N,B]$. (One may also use prove this result without Jacobson's lemma. See Aphelli's comment below.) Now rewrite $N=[N,B]$ as
$$
NB=(B+I)N.
$$
It follows that $NB\ker(N)=(B+I)N\ker(N)=0$. That is, $B\ker(N)\subseteq\ker(N)$. We may then prove by mathematical induction that $B\ker(N^k)\subseteq\ker(N^k)$ for every $k\ge1$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
N^{k+1}B\ker(N^{k+1})
&=N^kNB\ker(N^{k+1})\\
&=N^k(B+I)N\ker(N^{k+1})\\
&\subseteq N^k(B+I)\ker(N^k)\\
&\subseteq N^kB\ker(N^k)+N^k\ker(N^k)\\
&\subseteq N^k\ker(N^k)+N^k\ker(N^k)\\
&=0.
\end{aligned}
$$
Let $m$ be the index of nilpotence of $N$. Then $\ker(N)\subseteq\ker(N^2)\subseteq\cdots\subseteq\ker(N^{m-1})=\mathbb C^n$. Let $n_k=\operatorname{nullity}(N^k)$. Extend a basis $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_{n_1}\}$ of $\ker(N)$ to a basis of $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_{n_2}\}$ of $\ker(N^2)$ and so on until we obtain a basis $\mathscr B=\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$ of $\mathbb C^n$ such that $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_{n_k}\}$ is a basis of $\ker(N^k)$ for each $k\in\{1,2,\ldots,m-1\}$.

If we change the basis from the standard basis to $\mathscr B$, $B$ becomes a block triangular matrix and $N$ becomes a strictly block-upper triangular matrix. So, if we further triangularise each diagonal sub-block of $B$ (which leaves the corresponding diagonal sub-block of $N$ unchanged because it is zero), then $B$ and $N$ become simultaneously triangularised. Therefore $\det(sB+tN+zI)$ does not depend on $t$. In particular, we have $\det((x+y)B+xN+zI)=\det((x+y)B+yN+zI)$, i.e., $\det(xA+yB+zI)=\det(yA+xB+zI)$.

Comment: You’re assuming the conclusion to prove that $N$ is nilpotent, though, if I’m not mistaken. This part of the argument can be rescued by noting that since $N=NB-BN$, by induction $kN^k=N^kB-BN^k$, so that if $N$ isn’t nilpotent, $X \longmapsto XB-BX$ has infinitely many eigenvalues (or every power of $N$ has trace zero, therefore $N$ is nilpotent).

Comment: x+y≠0 so we cant put x=1 and y=-1 no?

Comment: @Aphelli Oh, I see what you meant now. Yes, you are absolutely right.

Comment: @StefanSolomon As mentioned by Aphelli, I should not have substituted anything into $x$ and $y$, as the statement determinant is what we want to prove rather than a given condition. But your question was posted long ago and I had not re-read your question carefully when I wrote my answer an hour ago. Anyway, whether $x+y=0$ is unimportant, as determinant is continuous in matrix entries. If equality holds for a dense set of $(x,y)$, it holds for all $(x,y)$.

Comment: @user1551 If I write $A=X+Y$ and $B=X-Y$ then $Y=YX-XY$ so $Y$ and $YX-XY$ are nilpotent. So $det(xA+yB+zI)=det((x+y)X+(x-y)Y+zI)$ and $det(yA+xB+zI)=det((x+y)X+(y-x)Y+zI)$. Now let $C=(x+y)X$ and $D=(x-y)Y$. We will need now to prove that $det(C+D+zI)=det(C-D+zI)$. I think this is an alternate way to do this problem but I dont really know how to finish. And the condition $x+y≠0$ tells us that $C$ is non-zero matrix if $X$ is non zero. How I can show that using the fact that $Y=YX-XY$ ?

Comment: @StefanSolomon Sorry, I have no idea.

Comment: @StefanSolomon: so what you want to show is that, given that $YX-XY=Y$, $\det(aX+bY+zI)$ is an even function of $b$. So it’s enough (up to adding a multiple of the identity to $X$, and using continuity) to show that $\det(aX+bY)=\det(aX-bY)$ assuming $X$ is invertible. But $\det(aX+bY)=b^n\det(X)\det(a/b\cdot I_n+X^{-1}Y)$. So we need to show that the characteristic polynomial of $X^{-1}Y$ has the same parity as that of $n$, so it’s enough to show that $X^{-1}Y$ is nilpotent. Well, $(X^{-1}Y)X-X(X^{-1}Y)=X^{-1}(YX)-X^{-1}(XY)=X^{-1}Y$, which concludes.

Comment: @Aphelli I dont really understand the part when you assume that $X$ is invertible. Can't we take $X$ as a limit of a sequence of invertible matrices?

Comment: That’s exactly what I’m doing. If the result is true for invertible $X$, then for any $X$, we can take a sequence of invertible matrices converging to $X$. The result holds for every matrix in the sequence, so holds for the limit.

Comment: @Aphelli sorry, can you explain showing $det(aX+bY)=det(aX-bY)$ implies $det(aX+bY+zI)=det(aX-bY+zI)$?